# HTML Slider to increase in 2 (Even Numbers)

Tags: html, slider

I have a slider for creating a flower pettals. The increase range is in 1. Is there any way to make the slider increase in 2's

Code of Slider:

```
<label for="pettalValues">Number of Pettals</label>
<input class"bar" type="range" data-theme="a" id="pettalValues" min="4" max="10" value="6"  data-mini="true" onchange="drawFlower()"/>
```

Code of Creating Pettals:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPetals; i++)
    {
      CREATES Ellipse SVG and Rotates Depepending on number of Petals Specified.
     }
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: No, for Microsoft Word. I've always been curious how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPetals; i++)
```

to

```
 for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPetals; i+=2)
```